# Difficult to understand Naive Bayes Predict() method

Tags: gaussian, naivebayes, email-spam

The below method is implementation of predict function in EMail Spam Detection project.

## Predict the class for a given row(mail)

```
def predict(summaries, inputVector):
    probabilities = calculateClassProbabilities(summaries, inputVector)
    bestLabel, bestProb = None, -1
    for classValue, probability in probabilities.items():
        #print(classValue,'->',probability)
        if bestLabel is None or probability > bestProb:
            bestProb = probability
            bestLabel = classValue
    return bestLabel
```

I am unable to understand how a particular data item is being classified as spam or ham by using above function

Answer (score 0):

The `calculateClassProbabilities` function is doing all the real work (probably has a spam-or-not score for every word in the dictionary, and sums the scores for the emails vocabulary).  That function returns a list of possible categories ("spam", "legit", "mass email you did sign up for but dpn't actually want to read") and associated probabilities.  The loop here just finds the category with the highest probability and returns it.